# How to fix my FreeNAS?

Tags: nas, freenas

I had a power interruption and my FreeNAS 9.2.1 install refuses to boot. I've watched the logs during loading and I get a few suspicious messages that seem to point to my auth configuration being broken.

- `pwd.getwuid(): uid not found 0`
- `malformed database schema (auth_group_permissions_<numbers>) - no such table: main.auth_group_permissions`

Searching the web hasn't turned up similar errors but I am able to get to the FreeNAS loader and one option is to "Load Defaults" - it's unclear to me if this risks losing the data on my NAS. Similarly, I could reinstall on the flash drive but I'm concerned about losing data.

Where can I look for further debugging or fixes?

**Notes**

- I'm running this on an old desktop with a 32 bit CPU. While I'd like to upgrade, that's not a possibility right now. Because of the limited memory, I'm also forced into UFS instead of ZFS, preventing me from upgrading FreeNAS further, since version 9.3+ forces ZFS

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot the server on a CDROM, getting a FreeBSD Live CD (see [https://people.freebsd.org/~blackend/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/using-live-cd.html](https://people.freebsd.org/%7Eblackend/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/using-live-cd.html)). From a Live CD, you may be able to diagnose further (are there a valid `/etc/passwd` file...) or backup your data. You seem to have a corrupted or absent database (in `/data/freenas-v1.db` or something like this according to https://joepaetzel.com/page/2/ I don't think there is a easy way to recover excepted the option you have pointed)

Comment: I am able to get into single-user mode which brings me to a prompt. I see a `/etc/passwd` file. I do not see a `/data/freenas-v1.db` file. In fact, the only thing in `/data` is `zfs/` which is itself empty. I'm further confused about its existence since I'm using UFS